# Particle で before もちきり

Tags: grammar, particle-で

I recently learnt the word もちきり. It always seems to preceeded by a word with particle で e.g.

> 最近、あなたの噂でもちきりよ
>   Rumours about you are a hot topic at the moment.

I can't understand why で is used. Which type of で is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word もちきり can be literally translated like "full loaded" or "loaded all the time", that figuratively describes a topic totally occupies people's tongues.

So, this **で** should be taken as *instrumental* "with", as in:

> アニメ**で**日本語を覚える *learn Japanese **with** anime*
>   仕事**で**忙しい *busy **with** work*

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

で particle can indicate location of action, time of action, means of action.

**で particle also indicates cause of an effect.**

In this case, **hot topic** is the effect of **rumors about you**. もちきりよ is an **effect**, and あなたの噂 is a **cause**.

Hope it helps.